# Problemas al actualizar datos por una carga masiva con un archivo excel.CSV

Tags: php, php5, phpexcel

Realizo un modulo en el cual es una actualización de datos pero es masiva por medio de un excel.CSV, tengo los siguientes campos en mi tabla "trabajador", algunos son llaves foráneas de otras tabla:

```
id_ControlPrimaria  
nombre  
ap_paterno  
ap_materno      
NSS 
CURP    
RFC     
fecha_nac   
id_puesto FK    
id_area FK  
idctg_turno FK  
idctg_empresa FK    
id_nomina FK
```

Lo que pretendo es que solo se **actualicen únicamente los datos del campo de `idctg_turno` conforme al `id_Control` y los otros datos queden intactos.** Anexo mi código de actualización masiva y también el query con el que actualiza, **el problema que tengo no se si es correcto el modo que lo estoy realizando ya que no actualiza ningún datos**. Gracias.

Es el código de modificación masiva:

```html
<?php
//nos permite recepcionar una variable que si exista y que no sea null
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
    require_once("conexion_excel.php");
    require_once("functions_actualizar_turno.php");

    $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
    $archivo_copiado = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $archivo_guardado = "copia_" . $archivo;

    //echo $archivo . "esta en la ruta temporal: " . $archivo_copiado;

    if (copy($archivo_copiado, $archivo_guardado)) {
        //echo "se copeo correctamente el archivo temporal a nuestra carpeta de trabajo <br/>";
    } else {
        //echo "hubo un error <br/>";
    }

    if (file_exists($archivo_guardado)) {
         $fp = fopen($archivo_guardado, "r"); //abrir un archivo
         $rows = 0;
         while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";")) {
                $rows ++;
               // echo $datos[0] . " " . $datos[1] . " " . $datos[2] . " " . $datos[3] . "<br/>";
            if ($rows > 1) {
                $resultado = actualizar_datos($datos[0], $datos[1], $datos[2], $datos[3], $datos[4], $datos[5], $datos[6], $datos[7], $datos[8], $datos[9], $datos[10], $datos[11], $datos[12]);
                if ($resultado) {
                    //echo "se inserto los datos correctamente<br/>";
                } else {
                    //echo "no se inserto <br/>";
                }
            }
         }
    } else {
        echo "No existe el archivo copiado <br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el código del query para actualizar los datos:

```html
<?php

function actualizar_datos($id_Control,$nombre,$ap_paterno,$ap_materno, $NSS, $CURP, $RFC, $fecha_nac, $id_puesto, $id_area, $idctg_turno, $idctg_empresa, $id_nomina) {
    global $conexion;
    $sentencia = "(UPDATE trabajador SET id_Control='$id_Control',nombre='$nombre', ap_paterno='$ap_paterno', ap_materno='$ap_materno', NSS='$NSS', CURP='$CURP', RFC='$RFC', fecha_nac='$fecha_nac', id_puesto='$id_puesto', id_area='$id_area', idctg_turno='$idctg_turno', idctg_empresa='$idctg_empresa', id_nomina='$id_nomina' WHERE id_Control=$id_Control)";
    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);

    return $ejecutar;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En MYSQL, Update funciona diferente a Insert mientras que Insert seria algo como

```
Insert Into trabajador (id_Control,nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, NSS, CURP, RFC, fecha_nac, id_puesto, id_area, idctg_turno, idctg_empresa, id_nomina) values ('$id_Control','$nombre','$ap_paterno','$ap_materno','$NSS','$CURP','$RFC','$fecha_nac','$id_puesto','$id_area','$idctg_turno','$idctg_empresa','$id_nomina')
```

Para update es mas de la forma:

```
UPDATE trabajador SET id_Control='$id_Control',nombre='$nombre', ap_paterno='$ap_paterno', ap_materno='$ap_materno', NSS='$NSS', CURP='$CURP', RFC='$RFC', fecha_nac='$fecha_nac', id_puesto='$id_puesto', id_area='$id_area', idctg_turno='$idctg_turno', idctg_empresa='$idctg_empresa', id_nomina='$id_nomina'...
```

Sin embargo el detalle es que aca debes incluir un WHERE para filtrar cual fila es la que quieres modificar, por que si no ejecutara el UPDATE para todas, asumiendo que la fila la determinaras por el id_Control seria:

```
UPDATE trabajador SET id_Control='$id_Control',nombre='$nombre', ap_paterno='$ap_paterno', ap_materno='$ap_materno', NSS='$NSS', CURP='$CURP', RFC='$RFC', fecha_nac='$fecha_nac', id_puesto='$id_puesto', id_area='$id_area', idctg_turno='$idctg_turno', idctg_empresa='$idctg_empresa', id_nomina='$id_nomina' WHERE id_Control=$id_Control
```

> PD: otro error que veo venir es que $nombre,$ap_paterno... etc no estan
>   definidas en ninguna parte (o almenos no las veo)

Comment: Tienes razón olvide corregir el código, pero ya con las correcciones que me hiciste favor de comentar aun no realiza la actualización de los datos